# CSS: transform не работает при движении курсора

Tags: css, вёрстка, transform

Для псевдокласса :hover блока block задан эффект transform: rotate(90deg);
Сам блок состоит из четырех круглых (border-radius: 50%) блоков, заполняющих только часть его пространства. 
Проблема в том, что эффект transform срабатывает только при остановке курсора на дочернем элементе. Сам блок block должен оставаться прозрачным, для него определены position: absolute и заданы height и width, то есть он имеет четкие координаты на странице. 
Как сделать, чтоб эффект работал по всей площади блока block в процессе движения курсора по оной?

Упрощенный пример для удобства восприятия:

```html
    <div class="block">
        <div class="subblock">1</div>
        <div class="subblock">1</div>
        <div class="subblock">1</div>
        <div class="subblock">1</div>
    </div>
```

```css
    .block {
        position: absolute;
        top: 50px; 
        left: 50px;
        widgt: 300px;
        height: 200px;        
    }
    .block:hover {
        transform: rotate(90deg);
        transition-duration: 0.6s;
        transition-delay: 0.5s;
    }
    .subblock {
        height: 30px;
        width: 30px;
        background-color: black;
        border-radius: 50%;  
        margin: 5px;
    }
```

[Ссылка на JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xku35fvc/)

Comment: добавьте блоку `.block` `border:solid` и увидите, что в процессе поворота блок уезжает из под мышки и ховер отменяется

Comment: Понял, спасибо! Но как можно от этого уйти? Хотелось бы без JS обойтись.
Сделать блок квадратным тоже не вариант - нужно, чтоб он был активным в одном месте, а смещался в другое.

Comment: может не поворачивать активную область?

Comment: Это анимация, используемая в качестве подсказки к работе кнопки. Такая реализация показалась мне самой простой, пока не столкнулся с этим.